# Autodesk Eagle - create arrays of vias

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, via

I want to connect the top and bottom layer with inner layers L2-GND. I've drawn a polygon and then renamed it as 'GND'.

Then I need to connect polygons on TOP and BOTTOM with vias.

Is it possible fill the polygons with vias automatically with Eagle?